# REST Saving GET history

Tags: rest, get

Reading about REST protocol I have seen that GET calls should not update the server / should be idempotent, so I thought: what if I want the user searches (made by a GET call) to be saved? My conclusion was that since it's an idempotent operation (first and N save have the same effect on server) it's ok in that case that a GET call modifies server data.

Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what if I want the user searches (made by a GET call) to be saved?

Sure, go right ahead.

> My conclusion was that since it's an idempotent operation (first and N save have the same effect on server) it's ok in that case that a GET call modifies server data.

Your conclusion is good, your reasoning is a bit soft.

Roy Fielding, [writing in 2002](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html)

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What
> it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and
> therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface
> or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that
> causes loss of property (money, BTW, is considered property for the
> sake of this definition).

The key idea here is the semantic distinction: the HTTP uniform interface defines that GET is [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are essentially read-only; i.e., the client does not request, and does not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of applying a safe method to a target resource.  Likewise, reasonable use of a safe method is not expected to cause any harm, loss of property, or unusual burden on the origin server.

The server can *handle* the request any way that it likes (including, for example, logging all of those requests).